# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testmod' Python doctest

Tags: windows, macos, python-2.7, doctest

When ever I try to doctest in python, basically whenever I run the code

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
   import doctest
   doctest.testmod()
```

I get this response from the interpreter

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testmod'

I can run this code just fine, but whenever I run it on my windows machine, it doesn't work.

My machine is running Windows theirs is OS X, but are running python 2.7.5.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that you are not trying to save your test file as `doctest.py`.  The print statement suggested above will show it.  If the file name is `doctest.py`, then rename it and try again.

Answer (score 4):

> `AttributeError`: 'module' object has no attribute 'testmod'

Clearly stats that the `doctest` module you're importing do not has the `testmod()` method.

Possible reasons can be:

- You have more than one `doctest` modules in the `lib`.
- and, it is the other one (without the `testmod()` method) which is getting imported as result of `import doctest`.

---

**Solution**: Look for the path of standard `doctest` module.

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
   import doctest
   if doctest.__file__  == "/path/to/standard/doctest-module":
       doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a different module called `doctest` that is being imported instead of the standard one.

To find out which module is being imported exactly, simply add the following `print`:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
   import doctest
   print doctest.__file__  # add this
   doctest.testmod()
```

The `print` should produce something similar to `C:\Python27\lib\doctest.pyc`, depending on the location and version of Python you're using. Any other output means you are importing the wrong module, and explain why you're getting the error.